# div inside while loop in php

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The search results should display like this [image]

But my results are stacking on top of each. [image]

Here is my code :

```
<div class="container">

<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("thesis") or die(mysql_error());

    $search = trim( $_POST['SearchKeywords']);

    $query = " SELECT * FROM new_data WHERE Product_Title or Product_link LIKE'%$search%' "; 

    $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    $count == 0;

    if ($count == 0) {

        echo "Sorry, Nothing Found !!";

    }else{

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
    {
        $img = $row ['Product_Img'];
        $link = $row ['Product_link'];
        $title = $row ['Product_Title'];
        $price = $row ['Product_Price'];
?>

<div class="card"> 
  <div class="front alert alert-success"> 
    <?php echo "$title"; 
         echo "<img src='$img' width='80px' height='100px'>"; 
         echo "$price"; ?> 
  </div> 
</div>
<?php
     };
    };
?>
</div>  <!-- Container -->
```

Those **div** blocks are inside a **container**. 
I added a bootstrap class in order for better a design.

Comment: Looks to be an CSS problem. Include stylesheets too.

Comment: try to use float in your card style and proper width in container style

Comment: Haven't added any CSS yet @Ahmad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a counter inside while loop.

Which will check, when there are already 4 blocks/ products in a single row then it will create a new row

```
<?php

    if($productCount == 0)
    {
        echo "<div class='row'>";               }
    }
        $productCount++;

    if($productCount==4)
    {
        echo "</div>" ;
        $productCount = 0;
    }
    
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [thumbnails with custom content](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails-custom-content)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well thanks for the hint, gonna look up now, hope it will help.

Comment: I did use the way you told me, but now it's showing like this :
http://imgur.com/RtoGcBX
All I want is to show the results like my 1st pic I posted at the top. I used float left but didn't work.